# Run Django query and time out after X seconds

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I want to build a function which takes a query in MariaDB/MySQL (it's the same [engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#mariadb-notes) in Django) and times out after X seconds and executes a faster, heuristical query.

I found a PostGreSQL example:

```
with transaction.atomic(), connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SET LOCAL statement_timeout TO 50;")
    try:
        return cursor.execute(my_query)
    except OperationalError:
        pass
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(heuristic_query)
        return int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

I want to do the same for MariaDB/MySQL but I [read](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aborting-statements/) that a) you have to set it directly before the query AND that the way `max_statement_time` is implemented in MariaDB and MySQL differs from one another.

Any ideas how I would build such a thing?

Thx!

**Update:**

The docs state that you set timeout like that:

> SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=100 FOR
> SELECT field1 FROM table_name ORDER BY field1;

But I can't prefix my queries because I don't have them as raw SQL and I don't have access to the place where the query is created.

Comment: You have already done the research, so not really sure what help you need from us. You habe to determine if the underlying database is mysql or mariadb and set the timeouts for the queries

Comment: I need the actual code  I didnt manage to find a proper example on how to use the statements.

Comment: The mariadb manual you linked contain sample sql statement and links to the mysql manual.

Comment: It contains a query saying you can put the settings directly in front of the query. But I dont want this, i want to create a transaction like in my example because I dont have access to the query and I dont want to mess around with raw queries more than necessary.

Comment: Then set it on session level.

Comment: Do you have a docs link somewhere how I can do that?

Comment: Using the SET statement.

Comment: I updated my question, I hope my issue becomes clearer then.

Comment: Please look at the set statement to set session variables.

Comment: I keep wondering if my approach is just not the right one. I want to define a fallback if my count takes too long and work with an estimate instead... Have to go into myself at some point and think about it again.